# UNIX Time stamp and MYSQL

Tags: php, mysql, timestamp

I am storing the date of entry in mysql via TIMESTAMP and default value UNIX_TIMESTAMP, however when I bring it back it's 2011-08-16 11:43:52 and if I try to style it with

```
<?= date('F j, o', $a['time']) ?>
```

It just does the timestamp from zero, bringing back December 31, 1970

Why? And how can I fix it?

Comment: Can you show the code you are using to bring it back?

Comment: are you sure $a['time'] is defined, that it's not $a['unix_time'] or something? That would do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A MySQL `TIMSTAMP` column is stored as `YYYY-MM-DD HH-MM-SS`, even if you input a `UNIX_TIMESTAMP` it will still be stored in that format.

So what you can do is:

```
<?= date('F j, o', strtotime($a['time'])) ?>
```

Demo: http://codepad.org/jBLR2KpH

Comment: better to select it as a timestamp directly from mysql, rather than forcing a 3-way mysql internal -> timestamp -> string -> php strtotime conversion series.

Answer (score 4):

Use

```
SELECT UNIX_TIMESTAMP(field)
```

When `UNIX_TIMESTAMP()` is used on a `TIMESTAMP` column, the function returns the internal timestamp value directly, with no implicit “string-to-Unix-timestamp” conversion.

[Manual](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_unix-timestamp)

Answer (score 0):

`date()` takes a number and not a string. MySQL always returns your date as a string regardless of its internal representation. Try this:

```
<?php echo date("F j, o", strtotime($a['time']); ?>
```